# Summation of function in for loop

Tags: python, function, for-loop, plot, sum

Im new to python, so have mercy if this question is quite trivial. The problem im struggling with is  plotting a function consitsing of many functions which are all different by their 'mode' numbers, I called them i and k. I think that the most efficient way for problems like this is provided by a for-loop.

My first guess was to use a code like this:

```
# Define vectors and lists
chi = sc.jn_zeros(0, order)
om = np.zeros((order, order))
P = [[0]*order]*order


for i, k in itertools.product(range(order), range(order)):
    om[i][k] = c*(np.sqrt(chi[i]/R)**2 + (pi*k/L))
    P[i][k] = lambda t: (N  np.sin(om[i][k] * t / 2)** 2 )/(2*om[i][k])**2)
print()

# sum up list of functions to one function
def p(t): 
return sum(sum(P, []))

# plot
t1 = np.arange(0.0, 5.0 * 10**(-9), 0.001*10**(-9))
plt.figure()
plt.plot(t1, p(t1))
plt.show()
```

However, I always get the error:

```
in p return sum(sum(P, []))
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'function'
```

My second guess is to avoid using a list and instead using a for-loop like:

```
def p(t):
    return 0*t

    for i, k in itertools.product(range(order), range(order)):
        om[i][k] = c*(np.sqrt(chi[i]/R)**2 + (pi*k/L))
      

       def p(t):
       return p(t) + (np.sin(om[i][k] * t ) ** 2 / (2*(om[i][k]) ** 2)
      
print()

t1 = np.arange(0.0, 5.0 * 10**(-9), 0.001*10**(-9))
plt.figure()
plt.plot(t1, p(t1))
plt.show()
```

Nevertheless the code does not produce a plot. There is only the output:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)
```

I havent found problems regarding the summation of more than two functions yet. Hence I would really appreciate if anyone could refer to a similar problem, or if someone can share some information about the errors occuring in my codes. I already checked if the variable vectors (omega, chi, ... ) are calculated correctly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code you pasted here is not correctly indented and contains syntax errors (like `return sum(sum(P[]))`, and so is clearly different from the one that generated the errors. Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to combine a set of functions like that.  You'll just need to run the loops every time.  Even if you did combine the functions, the net effect would still be the same.

```
# Define vectors and lists
chi = sc.jn_zeros(0, order)
om = np.zeros((order, order))

for i, k in itertools.product(range(order), range(order)):
    om[i][k] = c*(np.sqrt(chi[i]/R)**2 + (pi*k/L))
print()

def p(t): 
    return sum( 
        (np.sin(om[i][k] * t / 2)** 2 )/(2*om[i][k])**2)
        for i, k in itertools.product(range(order), range(order))
    )

# plot
t1 = np.arange(0.0, 5.0 * 10**(-9), 0.001*10**(-9))
pt = [p(t) for t in t1]
plt.figure()
plt.plot(t1, pt)
plt.show()
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you!